# Train an already trained model in Sagemaker and Huggingface without re-initialising

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, huggingface-transformers

Let's say I have successfully trained a model on some training data for 10 epochs. How can I then access the very same model and train for a further 10 epochs?

[In the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-checkpoints.html) it suggests "you need to specify a checkpoint output path through hyperparameters" --> how?

```py
# define my estimator the standard way
huggingface_estimator = HuggingFace(
    entry_point='train.py',
    source_dir='./scripts',
    instance_type='ml.p3.2xlarge',
    instance_count=1,
    role=role,
    transformers_version='4.10',
    pytorch_version='1.9',
    py_version='py38',
    hyperparameters = hyperparameters,
    metric_definitions=metric_definitions
)

# train the model
huggingface_estimator.fit(
    {'train': training_input_path, 'test': test_input_path}
)
```

If I run `huggingface_estimator.fit` again it will just start the whole thing over again and overwrite my previous training.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the relevant checkpoint save/load code in [Spot Instances - Amazon SageMaker x Hugging Face Transformers](https://github.com/huggingface/notebooks/blob/main/sagemaker/05_spot_instances/sagemaker-notebook.ipynb).
(The example enables Spot instances, but you can use on-demand).

1. In hyperparameters you set: `'output_dir':'/opt/ml/checkpoints'`.
2. You define a `checkpoint_s3_uri` in the Estimator (which is unique to the series of jobs you'll run).
3. You add code for train.py to support checkpointing:

> ```
> from transformers.trainer_utils import get_last_checkpoint
>
> # check if checkpoint existing if so continue training
> if get_last_checkpoint(args.output_dir) is not None:
>     logger.info("***** continue training *****")
>     last_checkpoint = get_last_checkpoint(args.output_dir)
>     trainer.train(resume_from_checkpoint=last_checkpoint)
> else:
>     trainer.train()
> ```

Comment: Fantastic! Full solution is 1. Add `hyperparameters['output_dir'] = '/opt/ml/checkpoints'` 2. Define a model checkpoint:  e.g. `base_job_name = "emotion-checkpointing"` and  `checkpoint_s3_uri = f's3://{sess.default_bucket()}/{base_job_name}/checkpoints'` and add the checkpoint to the estimator: `huggingface_estimator = HuggingFace( ..., checkpoint_s3_uri =checkpoint_s3_uri,)` 3. Add @gil's code sippet from the answer to your `train.py` file

Comment: [there is a good discussion about sagemaker checkpoints in the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-checkpoints.html#model-checkpoints-enable)